# Will there be a "lite" or "ThinPC" version of Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, embedded

With previous versions of Windows there are "lightweight" versions designed to be ran on embedded or less-capeable devices (XP Embedded, Windows 7 ThinPC, Windows 7 Embedded) which have a very low memory/cpu requirements and footprint. Will there be any Windows 8 versions like this or will it just be 8 and 8 RT?

Comment: The whole OS is designed as a mobile platform, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the looks of it, Windows 8 will support low-end devices, requiring 1GB RAM, 1GHz, 16GB HDD ([ref](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/Windows-8-Consumer-Preview-hardware-system-requirements,14847.html)). Windows RT will be pre-installed only, thus not portable to earlier devices.

Comment: That's quite low actually. Any word on what it needs, graphics-wise?

Comment: As @Akshat Mittal points out, this is probably not correct. As per hardware requirements, Wikipedia states that DirectX 9 graphic cards are supported: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8#Hardware_requirements

Comment: @HenningKlevjer - This answer is more correct then Akshat Mittal's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on these articles, Yes it will have a embedded version of Windows 8.

[ITWorld](http://www.itworld.com/256374/microsoft-previews-windows-8-embedded)
[Visual Studio Magazine](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/03/07/microsoft-releases-embedded-version-of-windows-8-for-ctp.aspx)

Windows RT is a different thing, Win RT will be Windows running on ARM, this is different from Embedded Systems.

Comment: Windows RT is not going to be used in embedded situations. The main reason is that Windows RT does not support those configrations, each Windows RT product will be built by Microsoft, but there will be a embedded Windows 8 product.  Future embedded systems MIGHT use Windows RT but the known Windows RT products for the next 6-8 months are already known.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes true!

Comment: @Ramhound: "each Windows RT product will be built by Microsoft" - You mean besides Surface RT there will be no 3rd party WinRT tablets?

Comment: @Karan As far as I know, Windows RT tablets can be made by other Manufacturers. Many tablets are known now also http://www.techradar.com/news/mobile-computing/tablets/windows-8-tablets-release-date-specs-and-prices-916134

Comment: @Akshat: Yep, that's why I was surprised by the quote above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there will be a Windows Embedded 8, and it is currently available to download as a CTP release from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/evaluate/windows-embedded-standard-8-ctp.aspx).